# creating child processes in parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, fork, parent-child

Say I have this piece of code

```
for (int n = 0; n < 4; ++n)
{
   if (fork())
   {
      // do something
      // if some condition is met
      // kill the parent
      // else, just return 
   }
   else
      printf("cannot get a process\n");
}
```

Would I be creating 4 child-processes running in parallel? Or would I be creating 4 of them running one after the other (because the loop in the parent won't advance until the child-process returns) ?

Thank you

P.S: I do realise this might be a bad practice (ie., killing the parent from a child causes zombies to go around, but let's ignore that for now!).

Comment: Do you realize that every child that is created will invoke `printf("cannot get a process\n");`?  Fork returns 0 in the child.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Sorry, why's that? None of the child-processes should get to the 'printf' statement, because that's only executed if fork() failed. And at the end of the if-block, I did say `kill the parent or just return (meaning kill the child)`

Comment: Because `fork` returns 0 in the child, the child's pid in the parent, and `-1` if it fails.

Comment: Killing the parent does not cause zombies.  When the parent dies, the child is immediately inherited by `init` which will immediately remove the child from the process table when it terminates preventing it from persisting as a zombie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-writing your code as:

```
for( int n = 0; n < 4; ++n ) {
    switch( fork()) { 
        case 0: /* child */
            /* Do stuff */
            exit( 0 );
        case -1:
            perror( "fork" );
            exit( 1 );
        default:  /* parent */
            /* do stuff, but don't wait() or terminate */
    } 
}
```

The children will indeed run in parallel.  Although it is entirely possible that one child will run quickly and terminate before the next runs, in which case the children are effectively running serially.  If the parent waits on a child, they will run serially.  Also, note that if the parent does not `wait()` here, and does not `wait` outside the loop, the children will become zombies when they terminate.  As soon as the parent terminates, the zombie children will be inherited by init, which will wait on them and remove them from the process table (so they will cease to be zombies.)

Comment: I think I understand more of what you said now, thanks! But I still need to clear up something that I'm unclear about. Will mark this as 'Answered' soon. Thanks again!

Comment: Add a semi-colon to do a no-op if you do not replace the comment with code.  eg `default: ;`

Comment: Ah, I see. (Java doesn't require this!)

Comment: inside the switch case statement, where fork returns a positive integer, you say do not wait(). using this exact code, how would you wait for the children after the for loop?

Comment: @JoseOrtiz, it depends.  If you just want to wait for any child to terminate, you could call `wait`.  If you want to wait for a specific process, you would use `wait3` or `wait4` or `waitpid`.

Comment: Ok, i just saw another post where they made an array of pid_t. When they fork() they set the return value of form to the array and later,  to wait for all children,  they used waitpid(pid[n], 0, 0) . Doing this, will the children still run in parallel?

Comment: @JoseOrtiz yes.  If the parent calls fork() multiple times, then multiple children will run.  If you have more than one processor, they will run in parallel.  If you have only one processor and they are long-running, they will contend for the cpu and the appearance of parallelism will be provided by the processes taking time slices. Calling any of the `wait*` family of functions doesn't affect the children while they are running.  (After they terminate, calling `wait` clears them from the process table.)